# wpf - listview - how do I add an extra header row to provide a visual grouping of related fields? (ie: Grid Band)

Tags: wpf, listview, header

I've got a wpf listview doing the gridview thing and I was wondering how I could add an extra header row above the field's headers?

I need to do this because this gridview shows a LOT of columns, all somewhat related to processes in a warehouse environment. The extra header provides a quick "Visual Grouping" of which fields in the grid are related.

In winforms world on 3rd party grid's they call this extra header row a "Band". I searched around but didn't see anything like this posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting here and on msdn about overriding a controltemplate to add in this extra header row I got no responses.

So I had to implement my functionality with labels stacked in a grid. I used dependency properties on my View and callback functions to handle size events and set the appropriate label width. I posted another question about this on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167279/wpf-bind-label-widths-to-calculated-length-property).

A bit hacky feeling, but it works until I can determine a better method.