# wpf - bind label widths to calculated length property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

If I had a label on a view that I wanted to have the width equal to the width of two columns in one of my grids on the same view, how would I set up the binding without using a converter? Should I use properties to preform my calculation and store a value?  It is my intention that if the view's grid size changes then this label's size will also change to match the new width of the two columns.

And where should I put this logic? I am trying to follow MVVM pattern but I see that a lot of threads about "converters in MVVM" say to put the logic into the viewmodel.

I tried to implement this behavior with dependency properties on my view since my viewmodel technically has no knowledge of my view (so how would my viewmodel know how wide my columns currently are?). This goes against what I have read online though. When implementing this behavior I noticed that I cannot reference my columns by name unless my property is not static, but dependency properties are static so I am not sure how to shuffle my values around without creating yet more properties to hold values.

Can someone provide help here? I feel like i'm overcomplicating this. I just need this label to sit over these two columns however they stretch. It just provides a visual grouping of related fields in the grid. Once I can do this first one, the other two should be equally similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My rule of thumb is if it's "View" related then keep it away from the ViewModel.  From your description this sounds like it's purely view related, so I would just use logic in either the codebehind or a converter.

Now what I don't understand is why you are reluctant to use Converters.  With converters you certainly don't want to store business logic that is going to lead to confusion or pain points for refactoring, but if you have some value that needs to be converted for a specific view operation then Converters are exactly what you should be using.

So my advice is Converters ... if it's View related then feel free to use Converters and Codebehind ... in fact you **should** use them and not the ViewModel.

Does that help?

Comment: I'm not against converters. I used them in some of my first wpf stuff. I've been trying to structure my wpf application approach to more of a mvvm-esque approach so my reluctance to use them is strictly based on "best practices" things i've read about mvvm. As with all things mvvm there's just as many opposing arguments that make a whole lot of sense of why I should still use them. It seems everyone's interpretation of mvvm has different separation boundaries so that's really what makes it difficult for me to choose the best fit for future usage.

Comment: I ended up not using a converter, but some dp's and some callback methods which did my calculation for me. I put it all in the view though since it was view-specific. Thanks for your input Chris.

Comment: Not a problem ... you made the right choice ... you went with what feels comfortable for you.  I don't believe anyone should do something just because it's "Best-Practice" and then they can't refactor or understand later.  Obviously you don't do anything that makes others live's difficult nor something that hinders scalability or isn't stable ... after that just do what feels right.  Good luck